# TiledLib for XNA throws ArgumentException on loading

Tags: c#, .net, xna

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is to load/draw a map from a Tiled map using Nick Gravelyn's TiledLib. The map is saved in Tiled's XML format. However, when I try loading the map with the line

```
TiledLib.Map map = Content.Load<TiledLib.Map>("Maps/Map1");
```

it throws an `ArgumentException`. The whole thing renders like this in Tiled itself:
[image]

The map's XML source looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/977344) (not posted directly onto StackOverflow for obvious size reasons).

It worked at first (with a pretty simple map using only one tileset) but when I edited it to include a bit more stuff then it suddenly started doing this. Could it be related to my usage of tile objects?

EDIT: I have been able to work out that using tile objects was not the culprit; [this map structure](https://gist.github.com/978347) still creates the same error.

Comment: I see nothing but a large scroll box.

Comment: @TheCommunistDuck I already noticed that, and I was already uploading it to another gist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you get an exception because you didn't name the objects in the map, this will cause ArgumentException in TiledLib. So, to solve this issue you need to go back to Tiled program, (re)edit this map, and select every object in the map and give it a name (not property but name)  then export the map again and (re)import it into the game content. This should fix the problem.

BTW: I recommend using regular layer for collide check not object layer. 
Like this: Make small png file with a transparent red rectangle tile in it in the same map tile dimensions, add new layer to the map, name it CollideLayer, and in this CollideLayer put  that red rectangle tile where you want to be a collide, and then in the game code you can check to see if the CollideLayer cell is empty or not. I find this is simpler.

Comment: The interesting thing is that I get a lot of warnings about it automatically setting names.

Comment: “automatically setting names” this option is not in my “Tiled Map Editor” copy(0.6.0) from http://www.mapeditor.org/ , but any way, You can do this manually by select the object layer then check “Select object” button on the toolbar then right click on any object on the map select “Object property” and fill the first field “Name”.

Comment: @Issam: Tiled doesn't, TiledLib does.

Comment: I think objects names should be set at map design time (on Tiled), so, TiledLib can use these names while loading the map because the exception here is thrown on loading the map.

Comment: @Issam: as it is now they are set on application compile time which is before the error occurs.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t get it, where exactly you set this option “Auto Names”?

Comment: @Issam: I don't, it just gives a few compile-time warnings about that it has already done it.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I mess understood your comments :) yes compiler gives warnings while trying to give map objects a unique names, but this not affects the tmx asset, which means the problem will rise again on deserializing. You can recheck it (double click on it on VS) it remains without changes (without names).

Comment: @Issam: yes, it actually did. Sounds like a bug to me, but thanks for helping with sorting it out.

Answer (score -2):

I',m guessing, but looking at your XML structure in the  section, there are a lot of repeats of

```
<tile gid="0"/>
```

in the data element. There is no documentation or schema definition on the structure of this file on the official site, and the content pipeline source is not available. Also, the demo of TileLib comes with that section as

```
<data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
```

H4sIAAAAAAAAC2NmYGBgpjKmFkA2jxCNrg+bHD7z0PWSYx428wmZjW4+qf7Fxyc3PnDFJS3jdzCbx4QFg8QZScTUzmcgDACR4mfdwAMAAA==

I'm not sure if you have an option to include encryption or not. But, the "gid" (global id ??) attribute cannot be the same for every tile defined if that is what it is. If I was writing this engine, I would have some way to readily identify each basic defined tile. Like a primary key on a data table. Which has to be unique. That would be the "gid" attribute for me.

Since the exception does not give any information (which is stupid - who deploys public libraries like that??), the argument exception is either that your "gid" attribute value is already defined, or that you're missing the encryption attributes which it expects in the pipeline importer or processor.

Comment: The XML structure is all generated by Tiled itself. The reason for it not looking like the example is because I turned off compression for testing and to make it more clear. After what I can see, "gid" in tiled tiles means the sprite id, where a 0 simply means none.